# USB Keyboard does not work! I have to use on-screen keyboard!

Tags: usb, disconnect

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 from my Ubuntu 12.04 USB which was created from Startup Disk Creator, and this computer is 12 year old computer when I installed Ubuntu 12.04 to make my 12 year computer a new life so I can use Ubuntu and I can even use my wireless mouse.

The worst problem is:

I have to use Onboard to use my keyboard which takes a long time! My keyboard (USB Keykoard - TECH-COM SSD-KB-805) does not work, I cannot even flash my Keyboard using my Number lock that the light does not appear after boot. Here is the dmesg of my USB Keyboard about:

```
# [  117.936042] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
# [  123.141447] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1c4f, idProduct=0002
# [  123.141463] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
# [  123.141469] usb 2-2: Product: USB Keykoard
# [  128.141085] usb 2-2: can't set config #1, error -110
# [  128.368114] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

What is causing the error -110 and disconnection of the USB Keykoard?

Comment: Googling a bit, to me it looks like the USB port does not provide enough power to the peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS setting for USB configuration. Make sure in "USB Legacy" is ON or AUTO, for enable BIOS to detect keyboard & mouse at bios.

in your case, 2004 pc should have 2 PS/2 port for keyboard and mouse, so using PS/2 converter is easy way to ensure compatibility with newer hardware.

Better use Lubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, Lubuntu is one of lowest requirement in Ubuntu fork. http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: I do not have a converter.

Comment: Have you checked the USB settings in your BIOS as @dika_saja recommended?

Comment: My bios says USB Legacy Support: All Device.